# Auctex, view a pdf already opened in Emacs 25

Tags: emacs, auctex

I have emacs 25.0.50 and auctex 11.88.

The auctex command C-c C-v opens a window with the pdf file (compiled with pdflatex). If that command is executed a second time, it does nothing. But in a previous version of auctex, in the second time the command puts the window with the pdf in front.  I would like to restore that behaviour. Is it possible?

Thank you!

Comment: What PDF viewer are you using?

Comment: i'm using evince 3.4.0

Comment: I don't think something has changed on the AUCTeX side, maybe this has something to do with Evince instead.  For what is worth, Okular still works as you describe

Comment: Leo, where is emacs25.. I must be in another internet, and was `C-c C-v` with sync-view? because with `(setq TeX-view-program-list '(("Evince" "evince %o")))` in the init file,  `C-c C-v` does what you want. and speaking of which, I never liked the idea of sync-view

Answer (score 1):

... Leo, unless I'm missing something, and under the assumption that `TeX-PDF-mode` is enabled (default now I think), two consecutive `C-c C-v` will call the viewer, as long as evince, is specified in `TeX-view-program-list` in the initialization file with a `(setq TeX-view-program-list '(("Evince" "evince %o")))`.

As @giordano pointed out, Okular works as expected, at least in my end, without further modification in the initialization file. Of course, this is after customizing `TeX-View-program-selection` variable, and selecting okular as default viewer for pdf files.

and by the way:

to have that functionality you wanted, **without** a `(setq TeX-view-program-list '(("Evince" "evince %o")))` in .emacs file, `TeX-evince-dbus-P :forward` must be removed in the `tex.el` file.

```
      ("Evince" ,(if (TeX-evince-dbus-p :forward)
         'TeX-evince-sync-view
```

make and compile auctex.

I'm aware that giordano might not agree with it.

And now that I think about it, wasn't there an issue with it before?